# set weekly limit basis on month

Tags: php, laravel, logic

i need a logic to set a weekly limit basis on month.

Eg:- weekly limit is 4,so user can do 4 post on weekly,but if next month starts,then the count should reset to 0.

current code:-

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$week_start_date = $now->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
$week_end_date = $now->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
$weeklimit = Payment::whereDate('created_at', '>=', $week_start_date)
                      ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $week_end_date)
                      ->where(['user_id' => $user_id])
                      ->whereIn('status', [0,2,4])
                      ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take maximum between **startOfWeek** and **StartOfMonth** for start date.

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$start = max($now->clone()->startOfWeek(), $now->clone()->startOfMonth())->format('Y-m-d');
$endOfWeek = $now->clone()->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d');
$weeklimit = Payment::whereDate('created_at', '>=', $start)
    ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $endOfWeek)
    ->where(['user_id' => $user_id])
    ->whereIn('status', [0,2,4])
    ->count();
```

But it means, that:

If it is Mai 31 (Monday), **I can post 4 times today** and from tomorrow (Jun 1, Tuesday) to the next weekend (Jun 6, Sunday) **I also can post 4 times**.

Comment: @ Method clone does not exist.

Comment: @Rp9
Which version of Carbon do you use?
change $now->clone() to (clone $now)

Comment: the max logic doesn't work. Becoz start of the week is may30 and start of the month is june 1, it will always return only jun1